# How do you recover a Facebook account without supplying a government issued ID if the DOB is set to 1900?

Tags: facebook

My friend set their DOB to 1/1/1900 and forgot their password. Now they can't log in. When they try to reset their password, it asks them to verify their DOB, but the options only go back to 1905. I even tried opening the developer console and changing the value 1905 to 1900 manually and submitting, but it still wouldn't accept it. How can they recover their account without supplying a government issued ID?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anyway to set it to 1900.

Additionally, your friend violated Facebook Terms of Service. It does not make sense to recover an account via verification that intentionally gave false information to being with.

On the sign up page

> Facebook requires all users to provide their real date of birth to encourage authenticity and provide only age-appropriate access to content. You will be able to hide this information from your profile if you wish, and its use is governed by the Facebook Privacy Policy.

Under [Facebook Terms](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php?ref=pf), here is what you need to be aware of

> **Registration and Account Security**
>
> Facebook users provide their real
>   names and information, and we need
>   your help to keep it that way. Here
>   are some commitments you make to us
>   relating to registering and
>   maintaining the security of your
>   account:
>
> - You will not provide any false personal information on Facebook, or
>     create an account for anyone other
>     than yourself without permission.
> - You will not create more than one personal profile.
> - If we disable your account, you will not create another one without our
>     permission.
> - You will keep your contact information accurate and up-to-date.

Your friend's option at this point I guess is that he/she somehow keeps being persistent with trying any contact to Facebook support (however as stated above I doubt this will happen)

The other option is make a new account (possibly from a different IP) and hope Facebook doesn't lock it down next time.

Comment: I changed my mind. This is a bad answer. The only way is to burn your email and make a new one? What if the person had that email for a long time? Facebook doesn't even have a way to update the info? That's just retarded. Part of your answer says "without our permission", but they don't even have a way to contact them!

Comment: @Chloe how about next time you don't use fake birthdays.

Comment: It wasn't my account. @phwd I'm thinking this will be the failure of Facebook. As Americans have more & more money, 3rd world scammers will try to hack into American Facebook accounts. Facebook will respond by creating obstacles for Americans to verify accounts. However, Americans will have more options and choices, and it wouldn't be worth their time or effort to jump through the hoops, and so will abandon Facebook altogether. Already my dad had his account locked too, and he just won't bother or deal with it. Time will tell...

Comment: @Chloe lol yes because only America exists on Facebook it's clear you don't want an answer you have an agenda. Please consult elsewhere.

Comment: I definitely would like an answer, but this isn't an answer. It can be summarized as "Your friend is SOL" or "Make new account". The more people I hear about being locked out the more I dislike it and see it as unjust and unfair.

Comment: @Chloe Your friend broke the TOS and you want an answer other than obvious. Yes, your friend is out of luck. Make a new account and get over it.